# Batch File Online Updater

Tags: batch-file, online-storage

Don't have any other name for this subject. Is there a way to make a batch file look for a file on a online storage site (EXAMPLE: Dropbox) and update.

here's an example: I am making a mod for a game that i want a batch file for updating and installing. the version of the mod is 1.0.0 and the online storage contains version 1.0.1. when you run the batch file, it'll say that there's an update available (it'll say you have latest update if you have latest version downloaded).

Anyway to do something like this or similar?

Comment: be more clear ... is it android , iphone ...

Comment: _IF_ the versions are named consistently and _IF_ they're listed in a public directory (Dropbox? Don't count on it.) and _IF_ you're willing to package third party software like cURL with your script, then yes.

Comment: @SomethingDark Thank you! thats all i wanted.. forgot to mention something like third party for batch... but thats what i needed.

Comment: but.. how to make it so if you have the latest version, it'll say that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not an option with Windows. Dropbox has options to access your files from the command line on Linux but not on Windows. It seems there is not enough demand for this feature although I would love to see it.